# What is the benefit of authenticating your Instagram javascript API?

Tags: javascript, instagram-api

I have seen examples online that pull Instagram data WITHOUT authenticating and some examples that do. Can someone explain why exactly someone would want to authenticate their application? I am trying to build a slideshow that pulls photos with a specific tag. The only issue I am having is that the feed doesn't pull from my friend's who have set their profile to private. Does authenticating the application help solve this problem of privacy?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way you can access private profiles using the API**

From Documentation:

> Authenticated requests require an access_token. ... We only require authentication in cases where your application is making requests on behalf of a user (commenting, liking, browsing a user’s feed, etc.).

Comment: Isn't that what the access token is used for? You can log in and start pulling photos from your friends?